# How do I modify all terms following a specific term in a list of terms?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words like so:

```
 list = ['I', 'did', 'not', 'enjoy', 'the', 'movie']
```

So, the aim is, if the word 'not' appears in the list of words, all of the following words should be concatenated with a 'NOT_' on their left side. For example, the output for the list above should be:

```
output_list = ['I', 'did', 'not', 'NOT_enjoy', 'NOT_the', 'NOT_movie']
```

Comment: A perfect example for a list comprehension.

Comment: @mic4ael possibly not, as *is this word after "not"?* would be awkward to express in that way.

Comment: @mic4ael: I'm not so sure a list comprehension is the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to start appending "NOT" after you've seen the 'not', here's an algorithm that might work:

```
seen_not = False
output_list = []
for item in input_list:
    if seen_not:
        output_list.append("NOT_" + item)
    else:
        output_list.append(item)

    if item == "not":
        seen_not = True
```

We construct a new list, adding items from the old list one by one. If we've already seen a 'not' in the old list, we simply append the modified word to the new list.

EDIT: I turned that code into a function named `mod_list` and tried it in the python interpreter:

```
>>> mod_list(['I', 'did', 'not', 'enjoy', 'the', 'movie'])
['I', 'did', 'not', 'NOT_enjoy', 'NOT_the', 'NOT_movie']
```

Comment: Yeahhh, I feel like it's a simple enough, and pervasive enough pattern that giving an answer in its entirety isn't morally wrong, but I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

What about searching the index of `not` and then change the part af the list after the index?

```
words = ['I', 'did', 'not', 'enjoy', 'the', 'movie']

try:
    idx = words.index('not') + 1
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    words[idx:] = map(lambda s: 'NOT_' + s, words[idx:])

print words
```

Result:

```
['I', 'did', 'not', 'NOT_enjoy', 'NOT_the', 'NOT_movie']
```

Answer (score 1):

This program appears to do as you requested:

```
def main():
    array = ['I', 'did', 'not', 'enjoy', 'the', 'movie']
    output_array = modify(array)
    print(output_array)

def modify(array):
    iterator, output_array = iter(array), []
    for word in iterator:
        output_array.append(word)
        if word.upper() == 'NOT':
            break
    for word in iterator:
        output_array.append('NOT_' + word)
    return output_array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can take a look at the output of the [same program](https://ideone.com/0BQGl4) on Ideone.com.

Answer (score 0):

a flag, two(wrong) -> one loop could figure it out.

> - if didn't find the location of 'not', flag is false;
> - if flag is false, output word without 'NOT_', else with a prefix 'NOT_'.

---

here is the reference code (Not good enough but keep it for a reminder):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
# Filename: test.py

__author__ = 'piratf'

flagWord = 'not'
prefixWord = 'NOT_'

srcList = ['I', 'did', 'not', 'enjoy', 'the', 'movie']

flag = -1;
for x in range(0, len(srcList)):
    if srcList[x] == flagWord:
        flag = x;
        break;
if (flag != -1):    
    for x in range(flag + 1, len(srcList)):
        srcList[x] = prefixWord + srcList[x];

print (srcList)
```

Additionally, `list` may not a good variable name for a list in python.